# In mule flow while using java transformer, will jvm hit once or multiple times if we have number of flows in one project

Tags: mule

I my project, I have 3 flows in mule studio in which i used java tyransformer. So, i want to clarify that whether all flows will be running in same JVM or different ones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same JVM, you can find more details [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Classloader+Control+in+Mule).

Answer (score 0):

All flows will be running on the same JVM and using the same classloader.